# How do I extract just src with beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
#page source for bs4
html = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  



thumbnail = (soup.find('div', attrs={ "class" : "preview"}))
```

Output

```
[<div class="preview">
<img alt="eye.jpg" src="https://thumb-service.domain.net/?sign=d85565637ccacf35673008b12871db54&amp;cdb=CPM&amp;fid=86274&amp;size=120&amp;format=jpg&amp;mtd=maxs&amp;mtdp=&amp;fp=&amp;ts=1461315108317" title="eye.jpg">
</img></div>]
```

I want just the src with & as &, I have searched and tried various suggestions but I cannot get this

Comment: You mean you want the value of the `src` attribute, unescaped? Navigate to the element and extract the attribute. Did you read the [*Navigating the tree* section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) of the manual? If you did, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Your output suggests you used `soup.find_all()`, not `soup.find()`. You have a *list* with a single element there, not just a single element.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the image tag itself with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
thumbnails = soup.select('div.preview img[src]')
for thumbnail in thumbnails:
    url = thumbnail['src']
```

The above CSS selector finds `<img>` tags with `src` attribute, inside a `<div>` with the class `preview`.

You you only need the *first* match, then use `select_one()`:

```
url = soup.select_one('div.preview img[src]')['src']
```